# Offlineimap and gmail 'All Mail' folder

Tags: email, sync, gmail

I'm trying to get offlineimap to synchronize (with reverse nametrans) with my gmail account. Here are relevant parts of my offlineimaprc:

```
[Repository gm_local]
nametrans = lambda folder: re.sub('spam', '[Google Mail].Spam',
                           re.sub('drafts', '[Google Mail].Drafts',
                           re.sub('sent', '[Google Mail].Sent Mail',
                           re.sub('bin', '[Google Mail].Bin',
                           re.sub('archive', '[Google Mail].All*', folder)))))

[Repository gm_remote]
nametrans = lambda folder: re.sub('.*Spam$', 'spam', 
                           re.sub('.*Drafts$', 'drafts', 
                           re.sub('.*Sent Mail$', 'sent', 
                           re.sub('.*Bin$', 'bin', 
                           re.sub('.*All$', 'archive', folder)))))
```

All the folders are synced correctly, apart from the stubborn 'All Mail' which I can't get to sync. How can I fix the problem with 'All Mail' synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're actually susbscribed to any folders you're missing sync on.

In my case, I forgot to check if I was actually subscribed to the "All Mail" folder in Gmail itself.